# File not found exception error in Java

Tags: java, filereader

I'm trying to read a file but I can't seem to make it work. It shows an error: "File not found exception". The system cannot find the file specified. I enclosed the code below. Can anyone solve this issue?

```java
package trailfiledemo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author VIGNESH
 */
public class Trailfiledemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

          FileReader fr=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\VIGNESH\\Documents\\ga and pso\\hellodata.txt");    
          int i;    
          while((i=fr.read())!=-1)    
          System.out.print((char)i);    
          fr.close(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: put the file somewhere without spaces, like `c:\\files\\javademo\\hellodata.txt` - does it still fail?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file exists within the designated file path as it needs to match. Another possibility that Joik mentioned above, is your compiler might not have permission to access the file within the path given. You could try an alternative file path if that is the case.

Answer (score -1):

FileNotFound exception has wrong name. It may appear not only in case the file is absent, so there is an ambiguity. 
There are three cases where a FileNotFoundException may be thrown:

1.The file does not exist.

2.The file is actually a directory.

3.The file cannot be opened. It may have no read access in your OS.

You need to check all 3 fail cases to be sure about the root of the issue. Documentation page contains some details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: I tried different path but no use.I checked read access by seeing the properties .It's perfect.

Comment: Well, good to know my answer is useful even with minus mark =)

Answer (score -1):

I implemented your code and only changed your username to mine and it compiled like a charm. Read everything in the file and ended succesfully.

Try:
Click on *Run > Clean and Build Project* maybe it didn't take one of your changes.

Other things you might want to try:
use a buffered reader:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\VIGNESH\\Documents\\ga and pso\\hellodata.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }
```

Or you could move the file into the same folder as the code and use this path '"src\stackoverflow\hellodata.txt"' *stackoverflow* => your package´s name

Comment: I tried your suggestions.still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @vignesh victory I added some solutions wich you might want to look into